# Android show data from Web Service

Tags: android

I have to show 9 columns, the first column it's a description of ítem, so this first column should be larger than the rest.

What object do you recommend to show the data? and how can I fix it the length for the first column?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, if you want to receive good answers it is recommended that you ask a question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can see what you have already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you should use a [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Comment: Did you read the documentation?  "The width of a column is defined by the row with the widest cell in that column. However, a TableLayout can specify certain columns as shrinkable or stretchable by calling setColumnShrinkable() or setColumnStretchable(). If marked as shrinkable, the column width can be shrunk to fit the table into its parent object. If marked as stretchable, it can expand in width to fit any extra space. The total width of the table is defined by its parent container."